# How can I correct this rounding down function?

Tags: python

How can I correct this rounding down function?

```
def round_down(num, prec):
    uod = round(num, prec)
    if uod > num:
        return uod - 1/10^prec  
    return uod
```

It raises: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'.

Comment: Give us a fully functional example, including how you're calling the function and what arguments you're passing it. Of course, your particular problem is just that you're trying to use `^` when you mean `**`.

Comment: and, as @mgilson pointed out, it is safer to use ``1./10.`` so that python uses floats and not integers (in which case the result will be ``0``)

Comment: After making that correction print(round_down(8.4789, 2)) gives 8.47 as required. I just assumed the problem was more profound. Must be careful with those assumptions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` does not mean what you think it means. Use [`**`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/power.html) instead.

[From the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

> The `^` operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments, which must be plain or long integers.

Also, as **mgilson** noted, `1/10` will equal `0` in Python 2.x, so you want to use `1.0/10` instead:

```
def round_down(num, prec):
    uod = round(num, prec)
    if uod > num:
        return uod - 1.0/10 ** prec  
    return uod
```

Comment: there's also the small issue that on python2.x, `1/10` will always be `0`

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll use 1./10 instead, although I am using Python 3 for this program.